# mySQL Update user information save null

Tags: php, mysql, null, save, string

I'm really not sure where to start for this one. I have researched code for days and can't really seem to find anything that plugs into the code I already have.

I feel like what I'm wanting to do is very basic; Allow a user to update a profile field by deleting it's contents and saving it as a blank value. Therefore, when it's blank, I have another code that chooses not to display that particular information if it's blank.

At this point, the field starts blank and stays blank if they leave it blank at registration but if at any point they save some information, information is always there. If you delete it and update the profile, the same information that you deleted still shows up.

I have a few files that are working together so I am having a hard time narrowing down the portion of code I need to edit to allow nulls to save. I have found what looks like a universal function to update fields - it is NOT specific to any one field (fname, lname, email, etc.).

```
  function updateUserField($username, $field, $value){
  $q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".$field." = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'";
  return mysql_query($q, $this->connection); }
```

I would assume this is the portion of code I would need to edit to allow fields to be saved even if they are blank but I am not sure what format of:

```
if (empty
```

to place and how it gets placed in this particular snippet of code.

Comment: echo $q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".$field." = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'"; what is shows? And,   '$value' And  '$username'  is string not variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it easy by using `""` (blank string) instead of using `NULL` to display an empty cell in the db. By this, you are overwriting the browser forms cache and no other actions are required when displaying the content (fe a check if it's a `NULL` or not... ).

When handling the form data, the $_POST["field"] will return a `""` if this field didn't got filled with data.

Also, you can reduce the data traffic by grouping your queries in one. Here below is an example, if you have three fields.

```
$q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".$field_1." = '$value1',  ".$field_2." = '$value2',  ".$field_3." = '$value3' WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Or use an array and pass it to the function with the above query.

Comment: This code is universal for all of the fields somehow lol. I don't have one for each field, just this one that apparently works for all fields and at this point I have about 26 fields. The thing with this code is that whenever you update information, you're using multiple commands from multiple files; session.php, process.php & database.php. It's tough for me to pinpoint where this "leave blank" command should go, what it should look like and where to insert it lol. I've messed with a few variations & some I have found on this forum and all over the web and I'm not finding a working solution.